# Criteria Workflow Issue

Tags: oracle, workflow, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I have a criteria workflow with only one step ,which is Review Step which has " Users can review and edit (replace) the current revision" selected .
The scenario is :

Author creates a content through webcenter content presenter taskflow and pushed it to the above mentioned criteria workflow.
The content goes for approval and the approver edits the content and after that the content is released in the system without going through the approval cycle where in the approver should approve the content after editing it.
Also even if the content item is in the workflow and approver has not approved the content and the author edits the content,the content is released in the system without going through the approval cycle ,which should not ideally happen ,it should go back to the workflow and only after approver approves it ,the content should be released.

What I want to know is whether this is OOTB behaviour that it will not go through the approval cycle after edit action has been performed.
Also,In case if its not OOTB , what are the ways where in I can push the content back to the criteria workflow after edit action has been performed.

Answer (score 1):

On the Content Check In form, the reviewer should check the Revision Finished Editing box. The content then goes to the next step in the workflow. **If the box is not selected, the content remains in Review status and must be approved before moving on through the workflow.**

Comment: From UCM console we can select or deselect the checkbox,but this behaviour is observed from Content presenter task flow from Web center portal.Thats the issue.